# How to get an IPs range from given CIDR

Tags: php

I want to get all IPs in the given subnet mask into an array using PHP.
Below is the code which executes fine in my XAMPP server , but the same code when I am trying to execute on live Server it gives no error and no out put.

```
$cidrArray = array("1.1.1.1/24","2.2.2.2/24","3.3.3.3/24");
$countCIDRarrayLength = count($cidrArray);
for($i=0;$i<$countCIDRarrayLength;$i++){
        $arrayCIDRwise = explode('/',$cidrArray[$i]);
        $bin = '';
for($j=1;$j<=32;$j++) {
    $bin .= $arrayCIDRwise[1] >= $j ? '1' : '0';
}

  $arrayCIDRwise[1] = bindec($bin);
   $ip = ip2long($arrayCIDRwise[0]);
   $nm = ip2long($arrayCIDRwise[1]);
   $nw = ($ip & $nm);
   $bc = $nw | (~$nm);
for($zm=1;($nw + $zm)<=($bc - 1);$zm++)
    {
    $all_ipArrray[] = long2ip($nw + $zm).  "<br/>";

    }
}
```

I got snippet of code from "http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php", over which I had built my logic to get all IPs of the netmask in a single array.

I used the snippet code but unable to understand meaning of below mentioned:

- $nw = ($ip & $nm);
- $bc = $nw | (~$nm);

Though versions of PHP are same on Server and on local server XAMPP.
The IP ranges I had defined above are dummy ranges of actual IPs.

Comment: `&` = bitwise AND, `|` = bitwise OR, `~` = NOT (or compliment)

Comment: But sir the code does not giving any output when executed over live server. When I tried to debug it I found that values of  $nw = ($ip & $nm);  $bc = $nw | (~$nm); are not evaluated and due to which final array doesnot filled with values.

Comment: try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` I got `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types` for ` $bc = $nw | (~$nm);`

Comment: I tried using error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); got same error as you mentioned. Is there any possible way to overcome this? If yes please suggest.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what method your using here but `ip2long` expects an ip address string but `$nm = ip2long($arrayCIDRwise[1]);` and `$arrayCIDRwise[1] = bindec($bin);` which will be an integer i'm guessing

Comment: PHP not giving any output and no errors usually means that your production server is configured very correctly not to show any errors to the outside world, and that it's a fatal error, usually coming from a configuration difference, missing modules or a different PHP version. Go look at your Apache logs.